# Is it possible to use single quote as quote character in fread?

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I have a `.csv` file similar to this one:

```
id,text,value
1,'foo, bar',5
2,'foo',5
3,'foo"bar',4
```

It uses single quotes for text.

I would like to read it in with `fread()`. I tried `fread('text.csv', quote = "\'")`, but I get 'unused argument' error. Is it possible to read the file in somehow? Can I somehow change the default quoting character?

(Using command line tool as `sed` to change the single quotes to double quotes also does not work as some field contains double quotes as well.)

Comment: `fread(x, quote="'")` works fine for me, where `x = "id,text,value\n1,'foo, bar',5\n2,'foo',5\n3,'foo\"bar',4"`

Comment: @Frank Strange. Not for me. I'm using `data.table 1.9.6`.

Comment: There's been a lot of updates in the development version to this end. Run `install.packages("data.table", type = "source",
    repos = "http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")` to install (currently 1.9.7).

Comment: Oh right, I forgot I was on 1.9.7.

Comment: Ah, so it is only possible in the development version.